# Coordinates around $(1, 0, 0)$ with a system of differential equations

Tags: differential-geometry

Are there coordinates $(s_1, s_2, s_3) \in \Bbb R^3$ around $(1, 0, 0)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s_1} = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s_2} = y \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - z \frac{\partial}{\partial y},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s_3} = z \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}.
$$
I understand that it is false, but I did not know why. I thought that considering a function in $S^2 \subset \Bbb R^3$ with the condition $f(x, y, z) = (xz, yz, z^2-1)$ but I didn't get anywhere.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you think the derivatives obey such equations?